# JavaScript Maps api using react native

Tags: react-native, google-maps, webview, maps, react-native-windows

Hello I'm actually new to windows app development and I'm trying to implement google maps in React Native windows app using the JavaScript Maps api and WebView.

```
index.html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b["google"]||(b["google"]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback","google.maps."+q);a.src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?'+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg", v: "weekly"});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
index.js

let map;

async function initMap() {
  const {Map} = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps');

  map = new Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8,
  });
}

initMap();
```

```
style.css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
 #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  /* 
   * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
   */
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

I'm trying to display the index.html in my Map custom component.

Output: blank screen

expected: google maps

Kindly guide me, where I went wrong.

Comment: Provide the WebView JSX code